# QRcode Reader for Monodroid

Tags: xamarin.android

I am using the following code to read the QRcode image using Zxing library. Iam taking a picture and passing the same to the QRcode reader to decode.

```
Reader barcodeReader = new MultiFormatReader();
LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(imagebytes, btmap.Width, btmap.Height);
BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
com.google.zxing.Result result = barcodeReader.decode(bitmap);
```

Is there any way to decode the QR code from the current camera screen without taking a picture. Please help

Answer (score 2):

Check out my fork of zxing.

https://github.com/chkn/zxing.MonoTouch

It includes a sample of doing a live scan from the camera:

https://github.com/chkn/zxing.MonoTouch/tree/master/sample/QrSample.Android